# How to return a promise in a nestjs interceptor?

Tags: typescript, promise, nestjs, observable

I have created a Class implementing NestInterceptor().

As it returns an Observable(), when I have a promise in it, it does not wait the promise to return the data. How should I do that?
Here is my code:

```
 export class PointsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
      intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body
var retour

//Using Promise
geocoder.geocode(monaddress)
.then(function(res) {
    console.log('res: '+ res);
    retour = res[0].latitude;
  
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    retour = err
  })  ;
  return next.handle().pipe(map(retour => ({ retour })))
}
}
```

**return** is executed before the geocoder promise.
I tried to put the return on success and error. A warning is rised:

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'undefined', 'void', nor 'any' must return a value.ts(2355)
```

**PS**: As this is a **nestJS interceptor**, I have to keep the class returning the Observable().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `async/await` syntax like below

```
async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
  var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body
  var retour

  cost res = await geocoder.geocode(monaddress)
  console.log('res: '+ res);
  retour = res[0].latitude;

  return next.handle().pipe(map(retour => ({ retour })));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After few modifications like:

```
    export class PointsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
      async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> { 
var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body
var retour

//Using Promise
const res = await geocoder.geocode(monaddress)
.then**(async** function(res) {
    console.log('res: '+ res);
    retour = res[0].latitude;
  
  })
  .catch(async function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    retour = err
  })  ;
  return next.handle().pipe(map(retour => ({ retour })))
}
}
```

It works fine.

Thanks